# __uint128 does not name a type

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile cmake-3.21.4 on aarch64-linux-gnu. I get the following error

```
e/root/cmake-3.21.4/Utilities  -c /home/root/cmake-3.21.4/Source/cmUVHandlePtr.cxx -o cmUVHandlePtr.o
In file included from /usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/signal.h:301,
                 from /usr/include/sys/param.h:28,
                 from /home/root/cmake-3.21.4/Utilities/cmlibuv/include/uv/unix.h:41,
                 from /home/root/cmake-3.21.4/Utilities/cmlibuv/include/uv.h:70,
                 from /home/root/cmake-3.21.4/Utilities/cm3p/uv.h:10,
                 from /home/root/cmake-3.21.4/Source/cmUVHandlePtr.h:11,
                 from /home/root/cmake-3.21.4/Source/cmUVHandlePtr.cxx:4:
/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/std_abs.h:84:29: error: '__uint128' does not name a type; did you mean '__int128'?
   84 |   inline _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR __GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/chrono:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/mutex:39,
                 from /home/root/cmake-3.21.4/Source/cmUVHandlePtr.cxx:8:
/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/limits:1635:11: error: '__uint128' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '__int128'?
 1635 |   __INT_N(__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0, __GLIBCXX_BITSIZE_INT_N_0,
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/limits:1635:3: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 1635 |   __INT_N(__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0, __GLIBCXX_BITSIZE_INT_N_0,
      |   ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/limits:1635:3: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 1635 |   __INT_N(__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0, __GLIBCXX_BITSIZE_INT_N_0,
      |   ^~~~~~~
```

I have searched through cmake source for __uint128 with no result. It's probably an issue with my c++ includes or gcc. What should I Do?

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem, the solution for me was to paste this code into the file that gave error:

```cpp
    typedef unsigned __int128 __uint128;
```

This code simply declares `__uint128`